# Events per time given time that an event takes to happen

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

In a book I read this affirmation: "Hard disks are reported as having a mean time to failure (MTTF) of about 10 to 50
years [5, 6]. Thus, on a storage cluster with 10,000 disks, we should expect on average
one disk to die per day."

I couldn't think how could we estimate the daily disks that die per day with only what I assume to be a confidence interval for the mean of disk duration. Is some information missing(and why)? And, with all the necessary information, how could we estimate the number of disks dying per day?

Comment: $365.25*10=3,652.5$; $3,652.5*5=18.262,5$. So, 10,000 days is within this interval, and the idea of one disk (out of 10,000) per day is consistent with the "10 to 50 years" finding. The problem is: I'm not sure they calculated a confidence interval and, if they did, I don't know how (i.e., I don't know assuming which distribution for the duration). In fact, for example, it could be that they just reported some publications talking about 10 years and others about 50 years.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that this is intended to be a rigorous calculation but just a rough estimate. If you take the mid point of 30 years and assume half the disks die by then, you get about one per day